# RecyclerView overlaps elements underneath

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I want to have two simple layout elements.
 
1. A RecyclerView that gets bigger through code. 
2. A LinearLayout with spinners underneath the RecyclerView. These spinners should always be visible.

What happens is that when the RecyclerView gets bigger, it overlaps the LinearLayout for the spinners.
Is there a way to limit the maximum height of the RecyclerView?

There has to be a simple solution, I feel kinda dumb as this should be so easy.

Edit:
I managed to achieve what I need by using negative margins. Is there a way to get the correct dp of a wrap_content-layout element? Does this work as intended on all devices and Android versions?

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.bla.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/header1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/header2"/>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_2"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add your screenshots and Xml Code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.bla.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/header1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/header2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_1"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_2"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: instead of progressbar, add spinner .

Comment: This solution adds a space but still pushes down the spinners.

Comment: please add your screenshots and Xml. Also add recyclerview item xml so that we can help you.

Comment: Added xml in question.